# Find multiplicative inverse when numbers are not coprime

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I want to calculate the value of $a$, given the equation:

$-8a\equiv 12 \mod26$

I know that i have to find the multiplicative inverse of $-8$, but since $\gcd(-8,26) \neq 1$, I suspect there can be 0 or many multiplicative inverses. Is this true ?
I read the wiki page, but it only says that if $\gcd(-8,26) = 1$ then I have a unique modular inverse, but it doesn't explain what happens in the general case...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that$$-8a\equiv12\pmod{26}\iff-4a\equiv6\pmod{13}.$$Can you take it from here?

Comment: $a=5$ satisfy the congruence, however i calculated it by hand...

Comment: When the numbers are so small, that's quite natural.

Comment: Thanks so much, it's clear. I have only one doubt , if i have $ax \equiv 12 \space mod26$ , why at prior i know that x must range from [0,..,25] ?

Comment: If $ax\equiv12\pmod{26}$ and if $x'\in\{0,1,\ldots,25\}$ is such that $x\equiv x'\pmod{26}$, then $ax'\equiv ax\equiv12\pmod{26}$.

Comment: Mhm this is not clear, do you know a theorem about this ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the elements of the residue class ring ${\Bbb Z}_n$, $n\geq 2$, are the zero, the units, and the zero divisors. Units are not zero divisors and are given by the elements $a$ with $\gcd(a,n)=1$. So in your case, the element is a zero divisor and thus has no inverse.

Comment: However, $-8*5\equiv 12 \mod26$ ...

Answer (score 1):

$$-8a\equiv 12\bmod 26\iff-4a\equiv 6\bmod 13\iff-2a\equiv3\equiv -10\bmod 13\\\iff -a\equiv-5\bmod 13\iff a\equiv 5\bmod 13$$

Therefore, a is 5 mod 13. Which is then either 5 or 18 mod 26.